# how can I strcat one character to array character in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, character, strcat

I want to get one character from `cin.get()` and add it to a array character. I use strcat but the single character has an error. please help me if you know. thanks for all answers.

```
void main (void)
{
 char e[80]="hi";
 char c;
 cin.get(c);
 strcat(e,c);
 cout << "e: " << e << endl;
 getch();
}
```

This is part of my code that I want to do this.

Comment: If only C++ had a standard `string` class to make this sort of thing easy and safe.

Comment: Perhaps `e[2] = c;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stncat()` concatenates two strings, method signature looks like this,

```
char * strncat ( char * destination, const char * source, size_t num );
```

but you are trying to concatenate a char which is not right!

As you are using C++, it is safe and easy to do it in C++ style rather than using C style.So use

```
std::string cAsStr(c);   // Make the string
e += aAsStr;             // + operator does the concatenation
```

If you are desperate to do it in the C style, use:

```
char cAsStr[] = { c, '\0' }; // Making a C-style string
strcat(e, cAsStr);           // Concatenate
```

Answer (score 2):

Change strcat(e,c) to strncat(e, &c, 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
char s[] = { c, 0 };
strcat(e, s);
```

But please, just use `std::string`:

```
string e="hi";
char c;
cin.get(c);
e += c;
cout << "e: " << e << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

A little change to your code would do it.

```
char e[80]="hi";
char c[2] = {0}; // This is made as an array of size 2
cin.get(c[0]); // Character is read into the first position.
strcat(e,c);
cout << "e: " << e << endl;
```

Comment: it makes one extra bit at the end of char c. but thanks I found it