# How to add a char/int to an char array in C?

Tags: c

How can I add '.' to the char Array := "Hello World" in C, so I get a char Array: "Hello World." The Question seems simple but I'm struggling.

Tried the following:

```
char str[1024];
char tmp = '.';

strcat(str, tmp);
```

But it does not work. It shows me the error: "passing argument 2 of ‘strcat’ makes pointer from integer without a cast"
I know that in C a char can be cast as int aswell. Do I have to convert the tmp to an char array aswell or is there a better solution?

Comment: Str contains no string, just the size declaration hehe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I strcat one character to array character in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522984/how-can-i-strcat-one-character-to-array-character-in-c)

Comment: That was just a example with Hello World to describe the Problem. It must be empty as first in my real program. Program will fill it later. The problem just contains to add a char/int to an char Array

Comment: @MikeCAT Wrong language.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`strcat` has the declaration:

```
char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src)
```

It expects 2 strings. [While this compiles:](http://ideone.com/F2WTgp)

```
char str[1024] = "Hello World";
char tmp = '.';

strcat(str, tmp);
```

It will cause bad memory issues because `strcat` is looking for a null terminated cstring. You can do this:

```
char str[1024] = "Hello World";
char tmp[2] = ".";

strcat(str, tmp);
```

[Live example.](http://ideone.com/VNtvIM)

If you really want to append a char you will need to make your own function. Something like this:

```
void append(char* s, char c) {
        int len = strlen(s);
        s[len] = c;
        s[len+1] = '\0';
}

append(str, tmp)
```

Of course you may also want to check your string size etc to make it memory safe.

Comment: I deleted my answer and support yours, you explained it better

Comment: This is the way to go.  Your append function will do the job.

Comment: I have to define char tmp[2] with a variable  from type char. (char temp = x; char tmp[2] = temp; ) but it tells me that I have a invalid initializer. Where is the problem?

Comment: @missjohanna just use the append function. You can't assign a char to a char[] they are different types.

Comment: Sorry I might be a bit annoying but I'm here to learn. Isn't one element of a char array not a char? In the Cache isnt it stored as char1 char2 char3... Why I cant change the value then of one of them?

Comment: @missjohanna sure, you can set the first element with tmp[0] = x. You need to either call tmp with a string literal char tmp[2] = "0" first or do tmp[1] = '\0' to ensure your string is null terminated.

Comment: @Kevin, this very much depends on your use. You should check with a debugger to ensure you are not exceeding the bounds of your string. If you still have a problem you can open a new question on this site. Just be sure to include an MCVE.

Comment: does strcat look for a NULL string in the char array passed as parameters?

Comment: @xyf what is a `NULL` string? Do you mean `"\0"` if so, this is a *zero length string* and yes, strcat will handle this by doing nothing.

Answer (score 3):

The error is due the fact that you are passing a wrong to `strcat()`. Look at `strcat()`'s prototype:

```
   char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
```

But you pass `char` as the second argument, which is obviously wrong.

Use [`snprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sprintf.3.html) instead.

```
char str[1024] = "Hello World";
char tmp = '.';
size_t len = strlen(str);

snprintf(str + len, sizeof str - len, "%c", tmp);
```

---

As commented by OP:

> That was just a example with Hello World to describe the Problem. It
>   must be empty as first in my real program. Program will fill it later.
>   The problem just contains to add a char/int to an char Array

In that case, `snprintf()` can handle it easily to "append" integer types to a char buffer too. The advantage of `snprintf()` is that it's more flexible to concatenate various types of data into a char buffer.

For example to concatenate a string, char and an int:

```
char str[1024];
ch tmp = '.';
int i = 5;

// Fill str here

snprintf(str + len, sizeof str - len, "%c%d", str, tmp, i);
```

Answer (score 1):

In C/C++ a string is an array of char terminated with a NULL byte (`'\0'`);

1. Your string str has not been initialized.
2. You must concatenate strings and you are trying to concatenate a single char (without the null byte so it's not a string) to a string.

The code should look like this:

```
char str[1024] = "Hello World"; //this will add all characters and a NULL byte to the array
char tmp[2] = "."; //this is a string with the dot 
strcat(str, tmp);  //here you concatenate the two strings
```

Note that you can assign a string literal to an array only during its declaration.
For example the following code is not permitted:

```
char str[1024];
str = "Hello World"; //FORBIDDEN
```

and should be replaced with

```
char str[1024];
strcpy(str, "Hello World"); //here you copy "Hello World" inside the src array
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've forgotten initialize your string "str": You need initialize the string before using strcat. And also you need that tmp were a string, not a single char. Try change this:

```
char str[1024]; // Only declares size
char tmp = '.';
```

for

```
char str[1024] = "Hello World";  //Now you have "Hello World" in str
char tmp[2] = ".";
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest replacing this:

```
char str[1024];
char tmp = '.';

strcat(str, tmp);
```

with this:

```
char str[1024] = {'\0'}; // set array to initial all NUL bytes
char tmp[] = "."; // create a string for the call to strcat()

strcat(str, tmp); //
```

Comment: That is a solution for the problem I gave as example. But I said one is a char array and the other one is a char. If it would be just 2 char arrays its no problem at all. In my main program I get a char or int from fgetc. It might work if I write: char tmp[2]; tmp[1] = fgetc(<file>); but not sure!

Comment: given your modification of the question, you might try: char newstr[strlen(str)+2] = {'\0'};   strcpy( newstr, str );  newstr[strlen(newstr)] = tmp;