# How to add/append character to a string?

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming and I'm trying to append characters to a string using `strcat`. I tried using what was discussed in this question: [How to add a char/int to an char array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055713/how-to-add-a-char-int-to-an-char-array-in-c), but it doesn't work. I keep getting `error: invalid initializer char characStr[2] = c;`. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thank you,

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char box[100] = "";

fp = fopen(filename, "r");

for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp)){

    char tempC[2] = c;

    strncat(box,tempC,1);
}
```

Comment: In this setup, you could keep the length of the string and just do `box[current_length++] = c;` in the loop and after the loop: `box[current_length] = '\0';` - but make sure that `current_length` never exceeds 99 when you use it as an index.

Comment: complete code please?

Comment: Try: `char tempC[2] = { c, 0 };` then you can then simply use `strcat(box, tempC)` (lack of bounds-checking notwithstanding).

Comment: `strcat()` is one of those functions that should almost never need to be used. To safely call it, you need to know the current length of the destination string, the length of the underlying array, and the length of the string you're adding, so that you can avoid buffer overflows. Given those numbers you can just use `memcpy()` or `strcpy()` instead, which is much more efficient because `strcat()` has to find the length of the destination again even though you already know it.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: @jarmod thank you, my code works with your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char box[100] = "";

int main()
{
  FILE* fp = fopen("somefilename", "r");
  int c;

  for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp)) {    
    char tempC[2];
    tempC[0] = c;
    tempC[1] = 0;
    strncat(box, tempC, 1);
  }
}
```

This compiles but it is terrible code:

- there is no check if `fopen` succeeds
- Using `strncat` here is very inefficient. As an exercise change this without using `strncat` or other `str...` functions.
- usage of a global variable without need